# Dynamic stored procedure to update a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

An application developer has asked me to create three different stored procedures to update the same table. Each stored procedure updates different columns and are called at different points in their application. I know there must be a way to create one combined stored procedure that could do the work.

At first, I tried to create a stored procedure with a "switch" parameter that would update the columns from each stored procedure based on the switch parameter.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Upd_table1] 
    (@switch INT, @ID INT, 
     @col1 INT, @col2 INT, @col3 INT, @col4 INT, @col5 INT,
     @col6 INT, @col7 INT, @col8 INT, @col9 INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@switch = 1)
        UPDATE dbo.table1
        SET col1 = @col1, col4 = @col4, col5 = @col5, col6 = @col6
        WHERE ID = @ID
    ELSE IF (@switch = 2)
        UPDATE dbo.table1
        SET col2 = @col2, col9 = @col9
        WHERE ID = @ID
    ELSE IF (@switch = 3)
        UPDATE dbo.table1
        SET col3 = @col3, col7 = @col7, col8 = @col8
        WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

This works as expected but I was wondering if there is a way to remove the switch and update the table with whatever parameters are supplied.

Comment: Did you try to use `CASE` expression?

Comment: There is, but it is not as efficient as the using a switch. You can write your update as `UPDATE dbo.table1 SET col1 = ISNULL(@col1, col1), col2=ISNULL(@col2, col2), ..., col9 = ISNULL(@col9, col9) WHERE ID = @ID`. This generates a fair amount of overhead, and doesn't handle cases where someone accidentally passes non-NULL values for the parameters that shouldn't be updated for this particular case.

Comment: @LaughingVergil  That was the one idea I had, but was wondering if there was a better way; appears not?  Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

I would use COALESCE: return the first non null parameter.

SET COL1 = COALESCE(@Col1, Col1) = if @Col1 IS NULL, take current value of col1.
Then, you update all your field in one operation.

```
UPDATE dbo.table1
        SET col1 = COALESCE(@col1,col1), col2=COALESCE(@col2,col2), col3=COALESCE(@col3,col3), etc...
        WHERE ID = @ID
```

Comment: As I noted in my comment above, this does add overhead to the procedure, and allows for incorrect updates.

Comment: @LaughingVergil yes, but if the application is build to prevent those incorrect update, this could be a solution.
I aggree that most of the case, the OP colleague is probably right: One stored procedures for each different case.

Comment: @Bestter And honestly, I was wondering if I was overthinking it by trying to create a procedure that would update whatever columns they designate. Is the initial switch idea one that is ok and doesn't create alot of overhead?

Comment: That won't work as expected, cause you are checking for `NULL` while OP need to check for the value of `@Switch` variable and depending on it update the table.

Comment: @Sami - Re-read OP's question. He asked if this could be done without passing a switch value.

Comment: @user1603398 - Either the ISNULL or COALESCE would update whatever parameters were passed in, and if this is what the user wants, this would be the most correct way to do that.

Comment: @Bestter - Agreed. However, I almost always find that assuming the developers will make a mistake (as everyone inevitably does) is the safer way to program, just like assuming that whoever is filling in data fields will make a blatant mistake if not prevented from doing so by the UI.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Frankly, I give you that one ;-). Still one stored procedures by scenario is probably the best, easier to debug, better performance, more precises code...

Comment: @Bestter - Agreed.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way that emulates the switch functionality based on the fact that there are no overlapping columns being updated between switches.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Upd_table1] (@switch INT, @ID INT, @col1 INT, @col2 INT, @col3 INT, @col4 INT, @col5 INT, @col6 INT, @col7 INT, @col8 INT, @col9 INT )
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Col1 IS NOT NULL AND @Col2 IS NULL AND @Col3 IS NULL -- switch = 1 equivalent
        UPDATE dbo.table1
            SET col1 = @col1, col4 = @col4, col5 = @col5, col6 = @col6
        WHERE ID = @ID
    ELSE IF @Col2 IS NOT NULL AND @Col1 IS NULL and @Col3 IS NULL -- switch = 2 equivalent
        UPDATE dbo.table1
            SET col2 = @col2, col9 = @col9
        WHERE ID = @ID
    ELSE IF @Col3 IS NOT NULL AND @Col1 IS NULL and @Col2 IS NULL -- switch = 2 equivalent
        UPDATE dbo.table1
            SET col3 = @col3, col7 = @col7, col8 = @col8
        WHERE ID = @ID
    ELSE
    -- Handle error case of incorrect parameters here
        RAISERROR('Incorrect Parameters passed to [Upd_table1]', 16, 1) -- sample error handler
END
```

Comment: @Bestter - I didn't say it was better, just that it performed the same task without passing in the switch value, and it does EXACTLY what the switch does (not updating extraneous values passed in) and calls out when an incorrect value is passed in in the key values checked.